# Showing index view for all categories in a survey

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails, I have two models, survey and category. Survey has_many categories and category belongs_to survey. I have an index page showing all of my surveys, and I want a button that directs the user to a view that shows an index of all of the categories for each individual survey. So basically I want them to click on the button and go to something like /surveys/:id/categories. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define the routes:

```
# config routes.rb
resources :surveys, only: [:index] do
  resources :categories, only: [:index]
end
```

Using `resources` gives us nice restful routes:

`$ rake routes`

```
           Prefix Verb URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
survey_categories GET /surveys/:survey_id/categories(.:format) categories#index
          surveys GET /surveys(.:format)
```

Checkout the prefix column - this means that we can get a path to the categories by `survey_categories_path(survey_id: @survey.to_param)`.

We then need a controller for categories:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # We use eager_load to get survey and categories in one DB query
    @survey = Survey.eager_load(:categories).find(params[:survey_id])
    @categories = @survey.categories
  end
end
```

Comment: THANK you, all I had to do was change @survey.to_param to survey.id in my survey index's loop, and she works!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

routes.rb

```
...
get 'surveys/:id/categories', :to => 'categories#index'
...
```

categories_controller:

```
...
def index
  @categories = Survey.find(params[:id]).categories
end
...
```

Comment: I would rather follow  the convention that rails uses when doing routes for nested resources  `/parent/:parent_id/child`. Its less confusing when you add a show action where `params[:id]` refers to the child, not the parent.